# show that $\frac{(y+z)(z+x)(x+y)}{xyz}$ is real and equal to$ 8 \cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \cos\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $x =\cos \alpha +i \sin\alpha$,  $y =\cos \beta +i \sin\beta $ and $z =\cos \gamma +i \sin\gamma$, then show that $\frac{(y+z)(z+x)(x+y)}{xyz}$ is real, and is equal to $ 8 \cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \cos\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: Do you know $cis(x) = e^{i x} = 1 \angle x$? Proving real is not too hard. I have proved $$\frac{(y+z)(z+x)(x+y)}{xyz}=2(1+\cos(\alpha - \beta)+\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha))$$ if I don't make any mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{(y+z)(z+x)(x+y)}{xyz} &= \left(\frac{y+z}{\sqrt{yz}}\right)\left(\frac{z+x}{\sqrt{zx}}\right)\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)\\
&= \left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{z}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}\right)\\
&=\left(2\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)\left(2\cos\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}\right)\left(2\cos\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)\\
&= 8\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}
\end{align*}
Another solution without using square roots:
\begin{align*}
x+y &= \cos \alpha + \cos \beta + i(\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)\\
&= 2\cos \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) + i 2\sin \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\\
&= 2\cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
Similarly, 
\begin{align*}
y+z &= 2\cos \left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}\right)\right)\\
z+x &= 2\cos \left(\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{\gamma+\alpha}{2}\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{\gamma+\alpha}{2}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
(x+y)&(y+z)(z+x) = 8\cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}\right)\text{cis}(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) \\
&= 8\cos \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}\right)xyz
\end{align*}

Comment: Since $\sqrt x$ is ambiguous when $x\in \mathbb C,$ it would be  better to  define, for the purpose of this Q, $\sqrt x= cis (\alpha /2)$ and similarly for $\sqrt y$ and $ \sqrt z.$ But the calculation is correct, and pleasantly simple.

Comment: @user254665. Thanks for the comment. I have added another solution that does not involve square roots.

Comment: What I had in mind was, in your first solution,  replace the symbols $\sqrt x, \sqrt y, \sqrt y$  with $ u,v,w $ where $ u=cis (\alpha  /2), $ etc.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, we could have computed that way. Thanks.